# The Person who become indifferent after they have achieved their goal

Tags: vocabulary

I want to know what do we call a person who becomes suddenly indifferent after they have achieved what they were looking for. 
In my mother tongue, there is an idiom for that, Turning eyes but it seems like it means something different when it comes to English.

Answer (score 2):

If an idiom works for you, consider saying the person *enjoys the thrill of the chase better than the catch.*

> **the thrill of the chase/hunt**
>   the excitement you feel when you are trying to get something that is difficult to get, especially when you are trying to get a romantic relationship with someone.
>   - https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/the-thrill-of-the-chase-hunt.